# Haxe Sublime Text

Tags: flash, sublimetext, haxe

I have a question about the Haxe plugin for Sublime Text and how to use it with flash libraries. Basically I have a .swc file I want to link in Haxe and I'm not sure how to edit this plugin or its settings to include the file. I know the command in Haxe3 to link .swc is just `-swf-lib library.swc` but I don't know where to put that command as it dynamically generates the .hxml build file. Any suggestions or ideas on how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

The plug in would pick up your custom "build.hxml" at the project root for completion and building. So you may simply add `-swf-lib path/to/lib.swc` there.